# Index vs Partition vs Multiple Tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table with billions of records.

So far we are indexing this table and we are thinking on partition this table based on a `Key` or creating multiple tables (one per each `Key`) to improve the performance.

What are the downsides/advantages of both approaches?

We are more inclined to use the multiple-table system since we may end up with over 1M partitions which seems unfeasible on Postgres.

Then we are planning to have some materialized views that depend on some of these new tables update every time the data changes.

Is this a good approach or should we just stick with the indexed table and for instance have a table that maps the `KEY` to the Materialized view?

Thanks

Comment: @jjanes I've changed my question. It's not based on the PK but on a key so each table would have thousands of records.

Comment: Thousands of rows per partition is too few, and millions of partitions is too many.  Maybe you  could range or hash partition instead to have fewer partitions with more rows each.  But partitioning is not a magic go-fast button.  Unless your partitions are carefully aligned with how you query the data, they will most likely make queries slower, not faster.  The best use of partitioning is generally to align it with how you get rid of obsolete data.

Comment: And to add on to jjanes' point "*The best use of partitioning is generally to align it with how you get rid of obsolete data.*" - Partitioning is a linear data reduction function. [B-Tree] indexes are a logarithmic data reduction function. That means indexes are exponentially faster at reducing (searching) data than partitioning is. Partitioning is typically good for improving data management (e.g. DDL) and have some edge case performance benefits for specialized scenarios, but for your day to day DQL and DML queries (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc), proper indexing should be sufficient.

Comment: What are the data inside the table? Logs or customer's data? Can you divide the table per year or per customer? Is that an option?